# Rails4: collection_check_boxes from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

There is some way to serialize a collection_check_boxes from one constant?
Something like this:

```
# model
class tutorial < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :option
  TYPES = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
end

# view
<%= form_for(@tutorial) do |b| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:option, Tutorial::TYPES, :id, :name) do |b| %>
         <%= b.label class:"label-checkbox" do%>
         <%=b.check_box + b.text%>
      <%end%>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Or just:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :option, Tutorial::TYPES, :id, :name %>
```

When I try both it I get the error:

```
undefined method `id' for "Option\t1":String
```

My permit parameters are already set with `option: []`

Someone did something like that before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The definition is:

```
collection_check_boxes(method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)`
```

The first one is a method to send, the second is a collection, the third is a method which is called to set an option value `property`, and the fourth is a method that is called to get a text and place it as a label for an option.

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :option, Tutorial::TYPES, :id, :name %>
```

There you are using `Tutorial::TYPES` (which is an array if strings) as a collection, and call `id` and `name` methods on each string.

Your collection should be `Tutorial.all`, and to get a label, you should implement a method on a `Tutorial` object for that, for example:

```
enum type: [
  :type1,
  :type2,
  :type3,
]
```

And use it like this:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :option, Tutorial.all, :id, :type %>
```

Comment: But using 'Tutorial.all' I do a query from model. This is exactly what I do not want to do. Whats I need is call it from array, like we do when we use the 'select' helper: <%= f.select(:lang, options_for_select(User::LANGS, @user.lang), {}, {} ) %>

Comment: @FernandoAureliano okay, then two last elements should not be `:id` and `:name` because these are methods that you call on each element of collection, so you're trying to call `:id` and `:name` on `"Option 1":String`. You can change `TYPES` to hash where keys or values are indices, and use it like that: `<%= f.collection_check_boxes :option, Tutorial::TYPES, :key, :value %>`.

Comment: Got the same error `undefined method key' for [1,` using an array like: `[[1, "option 1"], [2, "option  2"], [3, "option 3"]]`

Comment: @FernandoAureliano of course, if you're using an array, there's no `key` or `value` methods. You should use `:first` and `:last` instead.